# Upload Files to S3 using POST from different servers with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wan to achieve below. I have 10 log servers and 10 web servers in different locations. Every location has a pair i.e 1 log server and 1 web server. In S3 for every pair of servers, there is a bucket for storing logs like Location 1, Location 2, location 3.

I want to upload logs from every location to its respective buckets. I can do that with awscli but for that i have to create Iam user for every location and attach a s3 policy and put in access keys and secret keys in every location. I do not want this approach.

Instead, i was thinking that i would embed my access keys and secret access keys in every web server and then using AWS Signature version 4 , i would generate a signature for every file with respect to its bucket and upload to S3.

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import requests
import logging

LOGGER = None

def sign(secret_key, msg):
    return hmac.new(secret_key, msg.encode("utf-8"),hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + secret_key).encode('utf-8'), date_stamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
return kSigning

def S3UploadPolicy(date_stampfiso,customer_name, amz_date,credential):
    params = {}
    params['expiration'] = date_stampfiso
    params['conditions'] = [{'bucket': customer_name},
                        {'acl': 'private'},
                        {'success_action_status': '201'},
                        ['starts_with', '', ''],
                        {'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'},
                        {'x-amz-credential': credential},
                        {'x-amz-date': amz_date}]
    params = json.dumps(params)
return params

def S3Upload(access_key,date_stamp,date_stampfiso,customer_name, amz_date, regionName, secret_key, serviceName, filename):

    host = '<bucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com'
    endpoint_url = 'http://' + customer_name + '.s3.amazonaws.com'
    #content_type =  'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'
    content_type =  'text/plain'
    #method = 'POST'
    method = 'PUT'

    canonical_uri = '/' + customer_name
    canonical_querystring = filename
    canonical_headers = 'content-type:' + content_type + '\n' + 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amz_date + '\n'

    credential_scope = date_stamp + '/' + regionName + '/' + serviceName + '/' + 'aws4_request'

   signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'

    policy = S3UploadPolicy(date_stampfiso,customer_name, amz_date,credential_scope)
   policyBase64 = base64.b64encode(policy)
   payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(policyBase64).hexdigest()

   canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash

xamzalgorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
algorithm = xamzalgorithm

string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' + amz_date + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()

signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName)

signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' + 'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
print authorization_header
#sys.exit(1)
headers = {
    'content-type': content_type,
    'x-amz-date': amz_date,
    'authorization': authorization_header,
    'x-amz-content-sha256': payload_hash
}

try:
    print '\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
    print 'Request URL = ' + endpoint_url
    r = requests.put(endpoint_url, headers=headers)
    print '\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
    print 'Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code
    print r.text
except Exception as e:
    LOGGER.error(e)


def main():

    global LOGGER

    msg = ''
    access_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    customer_name = 'abc-test2'
    regionName = 'us-west-2'
    serviceName = 's3'
    filename = '/home/abc/abc.pem'

    logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(module)s [%(process)d %(thread)d] | [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s() ] | \n%(message)s')
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

## Calculate Date
t = datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
date_stamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')


date_stampf = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=24)
amz_date_future = date_stampf.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
date_stampfiso = date_stampf.isoformat()

S3Upload(access_key, date_stamp, date_stampfiso, customer_name, amz_date, regionName, secret_key, serviceName,
         filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: What is your question?